# Phpmyadmin trigger definition for updating specific column on another database table upon change to another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I've got two databases in the same server & i'll define them to be database_nevada & database_zurich with a table name `users` holding exact same column names in each databases:

-database_nevada.users
-database_zurich.users

I've created this trigger on `database_nevada.users` where every inserts to `database_nevada.users` table would insert the same row to `database_zurich.users` as well :

[image]

This works great without any issues.

But i'm unable to define a trigger for AFTER DELETE & AFTER UPDATE to replicate the same to database_zurich.users as well. If i take the example from the snip & define my trigger definition to be :

```
begin insert into database_zurich.users(id, name, email, password, access_token) values(new.id, new.name, new.email, new.password, new.access_token); end
```

How should the above definition be for updation ? Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html)

Your syntax doesn't include `CREATE TRIGGER` syntax. Also as a procedure/trigger can contain multiple statements separated by `;`, we need a different delimiter to let mysql know that all of the `create trigger` syntax is single statement.

Also it should be an update statement as this record would already be present in another database.

Note: Make sure you run this command in your database which is origin of your event i.e. `database_nevada`.

```
USE database_nevada; -- just to select proper database

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `users_after_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE  `database_zurich`.`users`
    SET name = NEW.name,
        email = NEW.email,
        password = NEW.password,
        access_token = NEW.access_token
    WHERE id = NEW.id;
END $$

DELIMITER ;   -- Resetting delimiter to default one.
```

For delete trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `users_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM `database_zurich`.`users` WHERE id = OLD.id;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you Jitendra...I'll try this..I'd request you to keep an eye to this post in case if you may have some doubts or hiccups while trying this.. really appreciate your assistance...ill mark this to be the answer if the end result is achieved